# Sufficent proof of funds

Tags: visas, ireland

I am thinking about visiting Cork for 5 days In September . I need a visa , and I'm worried about not meeting the sufficient funds requirement . I'm a university student and I'll be funding the trip by a money reward I won , It's not much , but it's enough for The activities I selected , tickets , accommodation . I also have a bank account,but I heard that I must have a bank account with at least 3000 euros,is showing the documents of paying enough?

Thanks for reading

Comment: The funds requirement is about two things. Being able to fund your trip, with a little left over for emergencies, and transparency about **how** and **why** you got the money to spend. It is not normal to spend many years' disposable income on five days in Cork. It might be normal to spend an unexpected award on five days in Cork.

Comment: See [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab) for guidance.